# Django access session from urls.py

Tags: django, session, django-urls

I have done a lot of searching about my problem but couldn't find an appropiate awnser. At least; one topic on Stack Overflow had the exact same heading as mine, but it didn't quiete help me. So here goes:

How do I access session data from the *urls.py* files? I tried importing through

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
HttpRequest.session['sessionVar']
```

But the error I get is that `HttpRequest` doesn't have an attribute called `session`.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You shouldn't need session variables inside urls file -- all logic operations should be coded in views. Why exactly you need session in urls.py?

Comment: I kinda would like to compose url patterns based on session variables so users can't access particular views. I think, that way i don't have to decorate each view i make (im doing a modular page, where users can access different module pages.)

Comment: I think this is not possible, because url patterns are not processed at every request but during application startup. I would recommend switching to django-way of doing this - using decoratos and views. Or maybe writing middleware and placing redirects there.

Answer (score 0):

You can read session data in your `views`, like below:

```
def myview(request):
    read_session = request.session['sessionVar']
    # ...
```